# Seaborn color brewer not interactive

Tags: python, seaborn, colorbrewer

I am trying to use Seaborn's interactive color brewer tool in Jupyter, however I am struggling to figure out how to use it interactively. Currently, it is just providing me with defaults.

[image: Seaborn color brewer]

Comment: Do you have `ipywidgets` installed?

Comment: Yes, `ipywidgets` version  7.4.2 with Jupyter Lab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn's interactive `choose_colorbrewer_palette` tool requires `ipywidgets` (or `IPython.html.widgets`). In order to be able to use those widgets in jupyter you need to activate them

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

For use in jupyter **lab** you also need to install the JupyterLab Extension

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

This requires `nodejs` to be installed.

So a complete install in conda may look like

```
> conda install seaborn juypter jupyterlab ipywidgets nodejs
> jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
> jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

The starting jupyter lab

```
> juypter lab
```

and typing in the code from the question works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I think the main things I was missing was `nodejs` and the most recent version of Jupyter lab (`conda update jupyterlab`)